# React Navigation back() and goBack() not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to go back two screens. The goal is to go from `EditPage` to `Cover`.  Here is my navigation stack:

`Main -> Cover -> EditCover -> EditPage`

I read the docs and it says to supply a key of the screen you want to go back from, here's my code:

```js
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({key: 'EditCover'}));
```

I've also tried (with no luck):

```js
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back('EditCover'));
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({key: 'EditCover'}));
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({routeName: 'EditCover'}));
this.props.navigation.goBack('EditCover');
this.props.navigation.goBack({key: 'EditCover'});
this.props.navigation.goBack({routeName: 'EditCover'});
```

The funny thing about all this is that I get no errors.  Nothing happens when the code is called...

P.S.  If I want to just go back one screen, this code works fine:

```js
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

P.S.S.  In case someone comes across this before there is a solution.  This hack works for now:

```js
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your StackNavigator please ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `key` property for [`goBack()`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back) is a dynamically created string, created by `react-navigation` whenever it navigates to a new route.

for example:
[image]

It is stored in [`this.props.navigation.state.key`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#state-the-screen-s-current-state-route).

So if you want to go from `EditPage` to `Cover`, what you have to do is to pass the key of `EditCover` down to `EditPage`, and then call `goBack()` with the key.

### Why not key of `Cover` but `EditCover`?

Because react-navigation only provides the method [`goBack(key)`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back), it's **go back from key**, not **go back to key**.

> Optionally provide a key, which specifies the route to go back from.
> By default, goBack will close the route that it is called from. If the
> goal is to go back anywhere, without specifying what is getting
> closed, call `.goBack(null);`

**EditCover.js**

```js
render() {
    const { state, navigate } = this.props.navigation;    
    const { key } = this.props.route;

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Go to Page" onPress={ () => {
                /* pass key down to *EditPage* */
                navigate('EditPage', { go_back_key: key });
            }} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**EditPage.js**

```js
render() {
    const { state, goBack } = this.props.navigation;    
    const { params } = this.props.route;

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Back to Cover" onPress={ () => {
                /* go back from *EditCover* to *Cover* */
                goBack(params.go_back_key);
            }} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 38):

The right way to do this is with StackNavigation:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: MainScreen},
    Cover: {screen: CoverScreen},
    EditCover: {screen: EditCoverScreen},
    EditPage: {screen: EditPageScreen},
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Main'
});

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppNavigator/>;
    }
}
```

According to your question, this is the order of your screens navigation, so when you **goBack(null)** if you are in

EditPage (goBack) -> EditCover (goBack) -> Cover (goBack) -> Main

You have to call **goBack(null)** like this in the components:

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
```

This is the right way.

Comment: @YvetteColomb thank you. I thought my comment was never posted for whatever reason. But why is it no longer needed? He can modify his answer to be more helpful, or to leave comment about why it's helpful. Rather than flag my normal comment as unkind.

Comment: @Val I deleted it, as it was flagged unkind (which is wasn't). But the OP replied, meaning they had read it. I figured it was no longer needed. As it was read. I didn't realise people may not know the comment was deleted. So sorry for being short. Your second comment was also flagged. That's the only reason I noticed you'd reposted. Have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm) and share the joys of moderating comments :)

Comment: Life saver answer +1

Answer (score 10):

In general we can use following two command

1. `this.props.navigation.goBack()`
2. `this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())`

we have to use two command in another case:

- first command useful in the project with One stacknavigator Only
- Second Command useful in bottom navigator.

In that case, One Tab of Bottom navigator will have some screen.
So Between a navigation of any tab and a navigation of another Tab, you can use second command.

Answer (score 6):

For new version react-navtigation you can use `StackActions`
As following:

```
 import { StackActions } from "react-navigation";

 const popAction = StackActions.pop({n: 1});
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(popAction);
```

This will return you back to the parent screen

Answer (score 4):

For React navigation 2 onward you can use

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())
```

Also do not forgot to mention in every stacknavigator

```
initialRouteName: 'Posts'
```

Answer (score 1):

For react native navigation v6 this works for me:

import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack());

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions