# this.props.navigation.goBack() is undefine and doesnt push back in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was trying to call the `this.props.navigation.goBack()` function after I modified the headerLeft icon:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={'VideoList'}
            screenOptions={{
              headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Video Details"
              component={VideoDetails}
              options={{
                headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                headerLeft: ({focused}) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image
                      source={icons.back}
                      resizeMode="contain"
                      style={{
                        width: 15,
                        height: 15,
                        marginLeft: 20,
                        tintColor: focused ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.secondary,
                      }}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ),
              }}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using an image to replace the `headerLeft`, however upon clicking the button via `TouchableOpacity` it doesn't redirect me to the previous screen.
The back button doesnt push back using `this.props.navigation.goBack();`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Navigation back() and goBack() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489343/react-navigation-back-and-goback-not-working)

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Same with this `this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
  headerLeft: ({onPress}) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
               {...}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
```

Comment: It works! can you explain why does it works and the `this.props.navigation.goBack()` didnt?

Comment: Yes if you go to definition of headerLeft you can see all supported props.

And also there is one writing mistake 
you are trying  onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack()}

correct method :
 onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()}
 onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack}

Comment: `onPress` works but `onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()} onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack}` did not work. Eitherway thanks!